# Are USB c headsets compatible with Linux?

Tags: usb, opensuse, microphone

just a quick question:
In the past I had problems with 3.5 because the audio worked but the microphone didn't work. I switched to a headset with USB A, where I no longer had any problems. Unfortunately, I am forced to buy a new headset. At the moment I prefer one with USB c because my laptop has this connection and it would also be advantageous for mobile devices.
Is there anyone who can help me and who knows if I will have problems with usb c? A working microphone is important to me for conferences. Or should I stick with USB A?
Hope I haven't forgotten any important information, of course I will update the post if I did.
Thank you!

Comment: Some are, some aren't. It depends on the audio chipset in the USB device.   Google "brand model linux" before buying (but note that some manufacturers change their hardware without bothering to change the model number - so if you can find out what chipset the device uses or its USB ID, search for that).  Or ask on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cas most should be. These days, it's all USB audio standard profile. Otherwise, their compatibility with smartphones would be bad and they'd sell badly.

Comment: @cas Thanks for the comments, unfortunately I couldn't find any useful information, it is the Microsoft Modern USB-C headset, on Amazon I was able to find the model number: I6N-00011, but could neither with 'brand model linux' nor with 'chipset' or 'USB ID' find something useful.  I often use Microsoft hardware without any problems with Linux, even the last headset was Microsoft. just nothing with usb c. Shouldn't it be more likely then, that it will work?

Answer (score 1):

USB-C is literally just the physical size and format of the connector. There are about a dozen or so protocols that use / allow / support USB-C connectors.

Without knowing what protocol the device uses, it is impossible to tell whether or not it will be supported. Heck, there is an even an [*Audio Adapter Accessory Alternate Mode*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Audio_Adapter_Accessory_Mode) which allows the use of USB-C for analog audio, so it is not even clear that there *is* such a thing as a "protocol" involved at all. It could just be that the headset is entirely analog and requires a sound card with a USB-C connector on the other end.

(Note that the latter is somewhat unlikely, because the specification explicitly forbids pure analog headsets to use the USB-C connector, but there are enough companies out there that violate the specification in all sorts of ways. For example, a non-negligible portion of USB cables violate the spec in ways that could not only lead to device damage but injury or even death.)

*IFF* the device *does* actually use the USB protocol and *IFF* the device is compliant with USB Audio Class 1.0 or 2.0, then it will work with the standard USB Audio Class driver that comes pre-installed on every Operating System for the last two decades or so. But if the device uses some proprietary protocol, then you need to verify that there exists a Linux driver (preferable an Open Source driver maintained as part of the Linux kernel) that is compatible with the audio system you are using (most likely ALSA).